In TradingView widget chart, how can I know when the chart is ready and data is loaded?
I'm adding a TradingView chart to my website, using Javascript.
I want to know when the chart is loaded and the data was loaded successfully, and print the success status in a dedicated textbox.
My code doesn't work, I added a onChartReady callback, but it never get there, even when the chart is loaded successfully.
Here is the relevant code I created:
    widget = new TradingView.widget({
        "width": "100%",
        "height": 500,
        "symbol": symbol,
        "interval": "D",
        "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
        "theme": "light",
        "style": "1",
        "locale": "en",
        "datafeed": "Datafeed",
        "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
        "enable_publishing": false,
        "allow_symbol_change": true,
        "container_id": "tradingview_widget",
    });
    
    widget.onChartReady(function () {
        chartLoaded = true;
        document.getElementById('result').textContent = "Chart loaded successfully!";
    });

I also tried to put the onChartReady inside the new TradingView.widget block, but it still doesn't work.
Any ideas what should I change in order to make it work?
